How to group columns with an odd index, based on columns with an even index?
I am the beginner of R programming. I have to group the dataframe in R by the condition such as: it's all odd number of column names need to grouped based on it's corresponding values present in the even number of columns. I have attached the example images.


I have used the following R script which I got from chatGPT, however it is not giving accurate result. Though it groups the values correctly, it returns more number of rows and the order of columns also changing in the output result.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

group_odd_by_even <- function(df) {
  # Get the column names
  col_names <- colnames(df)
  
  # Identify odd and even indexed columns
  odd_cols <- col_names[seq(1, length(col_names), by = 2)]
  even_cols <- col_names[seq(2, length(col_names), by = 2)]
  
  # Initialize an empty list to store grouped data
  grouped_list <- map2(odd_cols, even_cols, ~ {
    # Group odd columns by their respective even columns
    df %>%
      select(!!sym(.x), !!sym(.y)) %>%
      group_by(!!sym(.y)) %>%
      summarise(!!sym(.x) := paste(!!sym(.x), collapse = ", ")) %>%
      rename(!!sym(.y) := !!sym(.y))
  })
  
  # Reduce all grouped dataframes into a single dataframe by joining on even columns
  grouped_df <- reduce(grouped_list, ~full_join(.x, .y, by = intersect(colnames(.x), colnames(.y))))
  
  return(grouped_df)
}

The example input data,
structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 
4), col3 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), col4 = c(2, 3, 2, 3), col5 = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), col6 = c(1, 2, 3, 1), col7 = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), col8 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), col9 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), col10 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Please help me to write the generalized function for that. Thank you in advance.

Please show the code you've tried so far, and point out where it did not work out as you expected from documentation and tutorials.

If the even numbered cols indicate where the values of the odd numbered cols should appear I do not understand col3/col4. Shouldn't it be 1,2,1,2 instead of 2,3,2,3?

I have given example values only. The main thing is the order of columns only. The column names and the values are given for representative purpose only

The empty rows or empty cells need to be mentioned as 'NA'

A base R solution can be do.call(cbind, apply(matrix(colnames(df), ncol=2, byrow=T), 1, \(x) merge(aggregate(df[,c(x[1], x[2])], list(grp=df[,x[2]]), \(y) list(unique(y))), list(grp=seq_along(df[,1])), all=T)[,-1])). This also keeps the row positions of the grouped data.

I'd be curious to see any approaches that are simpler and shorter. Here's an approach using reshaping.
First I add row numbers for tracking, and reshape longer. From here, we can add variables to track which pair of columns we're in, and which type of column (value or group) we're in.
Then we can reshape wide again so each row has a grouping column and a value column. We can use summarize to concatenate the values within each group in each column pair.
And finally reshape wide again.
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-row, values_transform = as.character) |>
  mutate(pair_num = (row_number() + 1) %/% 2, 
         type = if_else(row_number() %% 2 == 1, "val", "grp"), .by = row) |>
  select(-name) |>

  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) |>
  summarize(vals = paste0(val, collapse = ", "),
            .by = c(pair_num, grp)) |>
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = pair_num) |>

  pivot_wider(names_from = pair_num, values_from = c(vals, grp), names_vary = "slowest") |>
  select(-row) |>
  `colnames<-`(colnames(df)) # apply original column names

Result (on provided input data, which varies from pictures in OP)
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7       col8  col9       col10
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>
1 A     1     A, C  2     A, D  1     A, B, C, D 1     A, B, C, D 1    
2 B     2     B, D  3     B     2     NA         NA    NA         NA   
3 C     3     NA    NA    C     3     NA         NA    NA         NA   
4 D     4     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA         NA    NA         NA  


Thank you @Jon Spring. Your answer is fine. However can you help me to get the orignal columns. In which place of the code I have to paste |> select(-row) |> `colnames<-`(colnames(df))`  this.

I am getting error while adding this script in the above function.. The order of columns also not as same as in the input data. The odd columns must have the names and the even columns must have the values.

Edited to swap column order and include column renaming. "I am getting error": what error?

Thank you so much. Now I am getting the expected answer.
